# how to trigger change event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

i am trying to make my 4th checkbox enabled as soon as there is a new value in my textbox (myinput).  If it is empty than disable this. At the moment you have to tab out before the changing event is triggered?
Also:how can I check for an empty textbox?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="myinput" type="text" onchange="Changing();" />
        <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" TextAlign="Right">
            <asp:ListItem Text="een">

            </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="twee">

            </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="drie">

            </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="vier">

            </asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script language="javascript">

    function Changing() {
        //alert('changing', document.getElementById('myinput').value);
        if (document.getElementById('myinput').value == '') {
            document.getElementById('ctl02_3').disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('ctl02_3').disabled = false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the onkeyup event which will fire as the textbox value changes.

See here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

Also the [onkeydown](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) and [onkeypress](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp) events will yield similar results